# Finding multiple spaces between two strings dynamically

Tags: python, implementation, string-matching

I'm writing code in Python and am taking two or more words from different variables and trying to find a match in the given text.

For example, two variables might be declared as follows:

```
string1 = 'Polluted' 
string2 = 'air'
```

And the text to match against might be:

`'Polluted\t\t\t air '` or `'Polluted\tair'`.

There may also be multiple spaces between words/tokens.

I need to find a solution that is similar to: `re.search(string1'\t+'string2,var)`

Can you help with a solution to implement this as intended?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`\s`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) which is equivalent to the set `[ \t\n\r\f\v]`, plus whatever is classified as space in the Unicode character properties database if `re.UNICODE` is used.

```
>>> var = 'Polluted\t\t\t air, Polluted\tair'
>>> re.findall(re.escape(string1) + '\s+' + re.escape(string2), var)
['Polluted\t\t\t air', 'Polluted\tair']

>>> re.search('(\w+)\s+(\w+)', 'Polluted\t\t\t air').groups()
('Polluted', 'air')
```

Comment: I think the questioner actually wants `re.search(re.escape(string1) + '\s+' + re.escape(string1), ...)`